# iOS Swift: How to do asynchronous/reactive/event programming for Swift 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3

We are trying to port our Android app to iOS using Swift 3.In our Android app, we use RxJava2 to improve the response time of our app. We get updates from GPS, iBeacons and CMMotionActivity.

We are noticing significant delays in iOS/Swift 3 app, because updates into iBeacon delegate are taking precedence over other delegates (in fact other delegates get called 3 times slower than normal because iBeacon delegate is taking over precedence).

a) How can I make sure all delegates get called with equal probability (as though they exist in isolation)

b) Is there a popular library or recommended approach for asynchronous/event based programming in Swift3 (similar to RxJava2 in Android world)

c) How to avoid interference between callbacks/delegates? I mean: assume  delegate for iBeacon gets fired while delegate for GPS is still in process. Should I synchronize my code to handle such situations or is there an easier/guaranteed way that OS ensures all delegates are called sequentially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When coming from `RxJava`, it would be a logical conclusion to consider its Swift counterpart [RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift). [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) is another functional reactive library, but you might encounter some confusing terminology when coming from the [ReactiveX](http://reactivex.io/) world. Both frameworks offer UI bindings, stream handling and scheduling.

The frameworks will help you greatly to orchestrate input from different sources. What you'll probably look for is a combination of streams, such as `combineLatest:` from `ReactiveCocoa` ([rxmarbles, image source](http://rxmarbles.com/#combineLatest)):

[image: combien latest]

Regarding manually prioritising delegate calls, you'll probably encounter difficulties. As far as I know, there is no way to reduce the frequency of callbacks from the beacon discovery. In a normal scenario, I don't think that this should be an issue that should concern you, as the different sources should not block/delay each other.